# Activating window of a variable workbook name

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know how to open a workbook that has a date in its name without knowing the date and activate its window.

Here is an example :

```
Dim src As Workbook
Set src = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Seats 2018-1-02.xlsx", True, True)

Windows("Seats 2018-1-02.xlsx").Activate

exportDate = Mid(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 22, 9) //extract export date
Range("M15").Select
```

How can I do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to activate the sheet. Since you are declaring an object for the sheet, when you call the method starting with "wb." you are selecting that object. For example, you can jump in between workbooks without activating anything like here:

```
Sub Test()

Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\xxxx\Desktop\test1.xls")
Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\xxxx\Desktop\test2.xls")

wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = 24
wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = 24
wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).Value = 54

End Sub
```

You also can find your file if you don't know the exact name :

```
Sub openAllFiles()

yourPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\xxxx\Desktop\"
file = Dir(yourPath & "Seats*.xlsx")
Do While file <> vbNullString
Workbooks.Open (yourPath & file)
file = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, i see now but already constructed my code the other way and i would need a big refatore to do it your way. can you help with how to open the file not knowing the date its title contains? thank you